# Curl header request returning 404 but body returning 200

Tags: php, curl, http-headers, content-type

I'm sending a header request with curl using the following code

```
function getContentType($u)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    $url = $u;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.12011-10-16 20:23:00");

    $results = split("\n", trim(curl_exec($ch)));
    print_r($results);
    foreach($results as $line) {
        if (strtok($line, ':') == 'Content-Type') {
            $parts = explode(":", $line);
            return trim($parts[1]);
        }
    }
}
```

For most websites it is returning correctly, although for some servers it is returning a 404 error when the page is actually available. I'm assuming this is because the servers have been configured to reject the header request.

I'm looking for a way to bypass this server header request rejection, or a way to tell if the header request has been rejected and is not in fact 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Setting CURLOPT_NOBODY to "true" with curl_setopt sets the request 
method to HEAD for HTTP(s) requests, and furthermore, cURL does not read 
any content even if a Content-Length header is found in the headers. 
However, setting CURLOPT_NOBODY back to "false" does *not* reset the 
request method back to GET. But because it is now "false", cURL will 
wait for content if the response contains a content-length header.
```

My guess is that you're using a HEAD request instead of GET and therefore getting rejected for it.

Comment: Yeah that is exactly what is happening, I'm simply looking for a solution as I do not want to download the entire page content with a get request :)

Comment: My guess is that HEAD isn't supported on some servers and therefore you'll have to fallback to GET, I don't really see any way around it